# Where can I find "ip_queue" module?

Tags: 12.10, modules

When I run: `modprobe ip_queue`, I get the error `FATAL: Module ip_queue not found`, but I installed `libnetfilter-queue-dev`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: ip_queue module is included in kernel (package linux-image-xxx-generic). You don't need to install any more packages. What's the output of `dpkg -S ip_queue.ko`?

Comment: dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern *ip_queue.ko*

Comment: My OS is ubuntu12.10

Answer (score 2):

[ip_queue is obsolete](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/iptables/+bug/1020598) and was removed from kernel 3.5.

From http://www.spinics.net/lists/netfilter-devel/msg21641.html:

> The nfnetlink_queue modules provides more advanced user-space packet
>   queueing mechanism.

You should migrate to nfnetlink_queue (provided by package libnfnetlink0).